# What is a good game involving coding?

Tags: survey

I remember the days of Shadowrun that got me excited about hacking.  There is CodeWar and LightBot which are both fun (though CoreWar is a little dated).  What other games are there involving coding that are fun and challenging that can be used to get someone excited about coding or flex their chops or even learn the basics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [RoboCode](https://robocode.sourceforge.io/)

You code your tank in Java and let it loose in the 'ring' with other coded tanks.  People got pretty into coding strategy, targeting, etc.  IBM sponsored it and came up with some nice introductory programming tutorials to get you started.

Here's a great article to get the feel for it:

[**Rock 'em, sock 'em Robocode!**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-robocode/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=89605))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

[Uplink](http://www.introversion.co.uk/uplink/home.html) isn't so much a coding game, but it is a great game that makes you feel like a hacker.

Comment: +1 It's got some networking concepts in it, plus basic encryption concepts…besides, it's just an awesome game in general. :D

Answer (score 5):

There's a whole bunch of "drag-and-drop" coding games, where you make a little thing (usually a robot) solve some puzzle by giving it a list of instructions. They're only vaguely similar to actual coding, but they are still pretty fun.

[RoboZZle](http://robozzle.com/)

[The Codex of Alchemical Engineering](http://www.zachtronicsindustries.com/alchemy/alchemy.htm)

[light-Bot](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Coolio_Niato/light-bot)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's considered a "game", but the [TopCoder Competitions](http://www.topcoder.com) are fun, and come in various sizes and commitment levels.  You can also work on puzzles from the archives for some good programming practice.

Answer (score 3):

[The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) is like those "look at the html source" riddles, but requires a bit of programming to get the answers.

Answer (score 2):

When I was a kid I played "Rocky's Boots", where you had to hook up logic gates to solve puzzles. That had a big impact on my thinking.

Answer (score 2):

[Core Wars.](http://www.corewars.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that allows you to *make* games and animations: [Alice](http://www.alice.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a board game, you might want to have a look at [Robo Rally](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/18). In this game 2-8 people are trying to maneuver their robots over the board as quickly as possible, dodging deadly obstacles and trying to shove other people robots into obstacles on the way.

Each game round all players have to "code" the program the robot is going to execute in the next round and then the robots just follow their program. The programs are just five instructions long, but still creating an optimal program can be quite tricky. There usually is very little luck involved, which is why I really like this game.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Uplink is [HackWars](http://hackwars.net). Instead of point and click hacking though, it's multiplayer and you can write your own attack scripts. There's actually an included runtime for writing 2d/3d games and there's a bunch of different places to hook in scripts (for defense, banking, in game website, etc).

Scripting language looks similar to Java.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Ai-Board](https://aiBoard.blog)

- You play it on your phone/tablet.
- It's IDE is built into the game.

[image]

It has a built-in node-based visual programming language, whose code-behind is a python-like language.

[image]

You write the code, that drives the Ai, that moves the pawns, that plays the game, all still on your mobile device.

[YouTube Video: Visual Programming Time-lapse on a mobile device](https://youtu.be/DIDgu9jrdLc)

[image]

It comes with quite a few tutorials that introduce the player to programming, genetic algorithms etc, and you get a step-by-step walk-through of all these methods.

It also comes with ready-made scripts that work right out of the box, and are ready for you to copy into your free 'Dev' & 'Test' envs,...

...so that you can tweak them to your heart's content, knowing that you can always revert to the original at any time.

The in-built machine learning engine allows you to

- train your AiBot to play the board-game,
- play your AiBot against their in-built Ai
- play against your own AiBot
- breed your AiBot (Genetic Algorithm)
- fine-tune your AiBot (Back-Propagation)

...debug your AiBot, and so on.

[YouTube Video: Machine Learning is mobile!](https://youtu.be/8oQmjUHGehQ)

Its currently in BETA testing, but soon to be released, and everything described comes for free.

In addition, there are single and multi-player modes as well, but it is primarily a game about coding, coming complete "...with batteries included!"

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft mods is good to learn java

Answer (score -1):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)